# how to access to number of download in andorid

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a program that download some file from a server. So I want to know how many time each file is downloaded. how can find this number?
Is it possible to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a feature in your app that you want to track usage of, try an analytics platform like Flurry, Google Analytics, MixPanel, etc. They let you set up events so that you can track every time a user does something, and then see it on a summary dashboard to "understand" it.

Comment: so you mean that using this API, I can access to number of downloads?

Comment: number of people who started the download from your app

Answer (score 0):

How many times your app downloads each file? Keep track of that in the code and if you are asking about across different runs then save the number, maybe in SharedPreferences. Even so the number of different files can grow real big over time (depending your app, of course) and you might need to deal with that growth. Also you might not know if two downloads of the same file have the same content even if the filename or URL are the same.

Across multiple apps (not yours)? Not sure if it is possible, but if it is your server maybe you can keep track of that on the server side?

Comment: It doesn't downloaded from my device it can download from different devices so the problem is here. if it was downloaded from my device I can count it. yes server is for myself. I rent it.